# git log not tracking updates after git fetch (in --no-checkout clone)

Tags: git

I have a git repository that I have cloned with `git clone --no-checkout <url>`.

After fetching the changes from the remote repository, however, `git log` does not show the latest commits.  `git log origin` does.  I don't want any working files, so I don't want to merge or pull.

To reproduce, do a clone from an existing git repository.  Then make (or wait for) some commits in the original repository (not the clone).  Then go back to the clone and do `git fetch`.  Observe that `git log` and `git log origin` show a different set of commits.

How can I get `git log` with no other arguments to show the latest commits instead of just the commits starting with the commit that was the latest when I did the original clone?  It's not clear to me how to "advance the pointer" so that `git log` shows the latest commits without checking out working files.

Comment: This—`git log` showing different tip commits after `git fetch`—would be the case in a repository cloned *without* `--no-checkout`, too. That's because `git log` by default starts from the commit identified by `HEAD`. Using `git fetch` does not affect `HEAD`, but does update `origin/*`, so the symbolic reference `origin/HEAD` will link to the updated `origin/main` or `origin/master` or whatever, and `git log origin` will therefore start from the last commit in their branch as copied to your remote-tracking `origin/*` names.

Comment: Given that you don't want anything checked out, but do want your own branch name(s) to update automatically, consider using `git clone --mirror`, which makes a bare clone that literally *can't* have any working-tree files (it has no working tree) and will immediately overwrite your own branches on each `git fetch`.

Comment: @torek - none of what you said is wrong in your comment, but it does not answer the question: how to change the default HEAD pointer without needing to check out working files. `git clone --mirror` sounds interesting.  I'll try that, but it seems to me that there must be a way to change the HEAD pointer without having to checkout files.  I haven't discovered it yet.

Comment: That's why it's a comment, not an answer. :-) What you're doing is not the way you're supposed to use Git, and you'll be fighting with it this way. There *is* a way to update the HEAD ref, but if you use it without a lot of caution, you can break things. First you'll have to resolve HEAD to a branch name, then you'll have to force Git to match this branch name to its remote-tracking counterpart. The `--mirror` way is better as there's no fighting with Git.

Answer (score -1):

You are using option

```
--no-checkout
```

This option implies no checkout of HEAD is performed after the clone is complete. So here you can see the current HEADs and tags.

I do not think without getting a working copy you can check all these details.

Comment: `git log --all` shows the new commits - still without a working copy.  So the information is there.  It's just that the current default pointer used by `git log` is not changed by `git fetch`.  So the question remains: how to change the pointer without checking out the working files.

Comment: Interesting, looking for the answer